# Evaluating conditional probability based on joint pdf

Tags: probability

My question is this

Let T1, T2 have the joint pdf e^-t2 for 0 < t1 < t2, and evaluate P(T1<=1 | T2>2). I know the conditional probability is the joint pdf/marginal, and in this case it will be the marginal for t2. I worked out the marginal pdf to be integral e^-t2 from 0 to t2. This makes my answer 1/2. But the actual answer is 1/3. They had the conditional probability as e^-t2/(3*e^-t2). Where did the 3 come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the support for the joint density is $\{(t_1,t_2): 0<t_1<t_2\}$ which means that

$\begin{align}\mathsf P(2<T_2) &=\int_2^\infty\int_0^{t_2}e^{-t_2}~\mathsf d t_1~\mathsf d t_2 \\[1ex] &=\int_2^\infty t_2~e^{-t_2}~\mathsf d t_2\\[1ex] & = \left[e^{-t_2}(t_2+1)\right]_{t_2=2}^{t_2\to\infty}\\[1ex] & = 3e^{-2}\end{align}$

Comment: That makes sense. Does the order matter in terms of the double integration? Or is the [0, t2] first because the conditional is given t2 > 2

Comment: @GeraldTan no, only because it is slightly easier to evaluate than $\int_0^2 \int_2^\infty e^{-t_2}~\mathsf d t_2~\mathsf d t_1+\int_2^\infty \int_{t_1}^\infty e^{-t_2}~\mathsf d t_2~\mathsf d t_1$